# Python Combinatory Algorithm - A Binomial Coefficient application with n mutable and k fixed to 2

Tags: python, algorithm

This question came from a real use case.
I had a data frame with different columns each one containing data from a data source and I wanted to design a hypothesis test to prove or not if the data had the same mean.
So I had to compute the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for each couple of columns.

**Now the problem can be generalized to any combinatory task.**

It follows that I had to implement a Binomial Coefficient like

$$ \binom{n}{k} $$

Where **n** is the number of columns

and **k** is = 2

**My question is**: if exists a more efficient way to apply a function on permutated samples taken from a list? And how to do this permutation  eg. Given a `func` and a list `[a,b,c,d]`

```
func(a,b)
func(a,c)
func(a,d)
func(b,c)
func(b,d)
func(c,d)
```

I created an algorithm to solve this issue, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do that **in Python**.

In my algorithm, I simply multiply each `n` element in an explanatory array with another element `i` of the same array, with `n!=i`, instead of computing the statistical test.

```
to_do=[1,2,3,4,5]
#done will store information on the elements already combined
done=[]
#j will store information on the results of the combination  
j=[]


#iterating over the to_do array
for n in to_do:

  #checking if we already computed the n element  
  if n not in done:
    print(n)
    #taking another i element from the array
    #where n!=i    
    for i in to_do: 
      print(i)
      #if the condition is satisfied       
      if i!=n:
        #combine the two elements        
        m=n*i

        #append the result on the "j" array 
        j.append(m)
    #updating the array with the "done" elements        
    done.append(n)    

print(len(done))
print(len(j))
```

Comment: Unclear. What exactly is the input, what exactly is the output? Do you just want `itertools.permutations(to_do, 2)`?

Comment: The input is the array ´to_do´ and then each element of the array is multiplied with another one and this operation should be done for each element.

Comment: I read the documentation, how can I avoid to repeat an operation when I have to permutate like in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) a list of 4 elements `[ABCD]` and I need only `AB` and not `BA` (or viceversa). I tried to fix this issue with the `done` array in my code

Comment: Well your own code does both AB and BA. Are you saying your code isn't correct and thus your question is off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the length of the list, your code can be reduced to one line:

```
result = len(to_do) * (len(to_do) - 1)
```

Also, you're comments are, at the very least, *excessive*. You should really only use comments to explain a design choice or a complicated equation/algorithm. Comments like `#if the condition is satisfied` just clutters your code.

As explained [in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253954/python-combinatory-algorithm-a-binomial-coefficient-application-with-n-mutable/253972?noredirect=1#comment500887_253972), actual computations need to be made. This can be done using `itertools.permutations`.

```
import itertools
from typing import List

def func(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:

    return list(set(
        x * y for x, y in itertools.permutations(nums, 2)
    ))
```

While this doesn't avoid the extra computations, it's a short and sweet solution. And below is how you would use it:

```
to_do = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
func(to_do)
```

Comment: Thank you the point about the comment is very useful, the output as I commented above is to multiply each element of the list with another one and this should be done for all the elements, except for the multiplication of the element ´i´ with itself.

Comment: @AndreaCiufo Please see my edited answer.

Comment: what does it mean `-> List[int]` it's the first time that I see it in the function signature?

Comment: @AndreaCiufo It means that the function returns a list of integers. Take a look at the [python docs regarding type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Answer (score 1):

> **My question is:** if exists a more efficient way to apply a function on
> permutated samples taken from a list? And how to do this permutation
> eg. Given a func and a list [a,b,c,d]
>
> func(a,b)
>
> func(a,c)
>
> func(a,d)
>
> func(b,c)
>
> func(b,d)
>
> func(c,d)

It seems that you are looking for combinations rather than permutations. In that case, use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations

for x, y in combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2):
    print(x, y)
```

It prints:

```
a b
a c
a d
b c
b d
c d
```

Using `itertools.combinations` in your example:

```
from itertools import combinations

todo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
j = [x * y for x, y in combinations(todo, 2)]
```